# Variable as key in value pair JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, keyvaluepair

Hi I am having trouble inserting my variable from controller in java script key value pair. Having real trouble reading debug in F12. Value is value but also is key and key is value.

Can't you just do: `inputRegions.key = myVariable` and `inputRegions.Value = myVariable2` ?

Sorry if it's a stupid question.

```
var inputRegions = [{ parsedData.Item1 : "#FFF000" }];
```

or even better

```
var cdata = { parsedData.Item1 : "#FFF000"}
```

Comment: ES2015 (The next version of JS - currently not broadly supported) allows for computed keys using the `[]` syntax, so maybe that'll help. It looks like this: `cdata = {[parsedData.Item1]:'#FFFFFF'}` - more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question (you just say "having trouble"). Do you want to create a key name that has a dot?

Comment: Yep it worked like you said. cdata = {[parsedData.Item1]:'#FFFFFF'}

Comment: `Value is value but also is key and key is value.` <--- Deep philosophy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var map = new Object(); // or var map = {};
map[myKey1] = myObj1;
map[myKey2] = myObj2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Current generally available JavaScript engines only allow static strings in object literals, thus you need temporary variables and a lot of boilerplate:

```
> var inputRegions  = [];
undefined
> var tmp = {};
undefined
> tmp["parsedData.Item1"] = "#FFF000";
'#FFF000'
> inputRegions.push(tmp);
1
> console.log(inputRegions);
[ { 'parsedData.Item1': '#FFF000' } ]
undefined
```